# Syntax errors when executing a complex command via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to know if a server is running and if not then i would like to start it. for this scenario I have written the following bash script

```
ssh -t machine "cd /to/the/bin/path 
  && if [ -n $(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep server_name | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}') ] 
     then 
          echo 'podsvr is running with 
             id $(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep POD | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')' 
     else 
          sudo -u dev sfservice server_name start 
     fi
"
```

When I run the above program I am getting the following error

> bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Could some one please help me in this regards

~Sunil

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest single quotes like that in bash. Change the second occurrence of:

```
 'FNR == 1 {print $1}'
```

To:

```
'\''FNR == 1 {print $1}'\''
```

Comment: I have modified the script as ssh -t machine "cd /to/the/bin/path && if [ -n $(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep server_name | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}') ] then echo 'server_name is running with
 id $(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep server_name | awk '\''FNR == 1 {print $1}'\'' else sudo -u dev sfservice server_name start fi" and now I am getting the error test1.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
test1.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Try putting double quotes around the first `$(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep server_name | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')` as well.

Comment: Even now I am getting the following error                        test1.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
test1.sh: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file.

Comment: @Paulpro you saved my day. Many thanks. My head is blowing up because I cannot understand how this works. Is this the standard way of nesting quotes in bash? Many thanks again. Daniele.

Comment: @DanieleBrugnara In bash, strings, quoted or not, get concatenated, so `"test test"test'test'` would be the same as `'test testtesttest'`. To add a quote between the `a` and `b` `'test'ab'test'`, we would escape it like `'test'a\'b'test'` which results in the string `testa'btest`. In an unquoted string the `\'` represents a literal `'` character.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is messed up. Probably the main problem is that you put the entire ssh script in double quotes. Since it's included in double quotes, the `$(...)` parts are already evaluated on the local machine before the result is passed to the remote one, and the results are fairly nonsensical. I would use the following recipe:

1. Write the script that should be executed on the remote machine. Preferably log in to the remote machine and test it there.
2. Now enclose the entire script in *single* quotes and replace **every** enclosed `'` by `'\''` or alternatively by `'"'"'`.
3. In case that the command contains a variable that should be evaluated on the *local* machine, put `'\'"` in front of it and `"\''` after it. For instance, if the command to be executed on the remote machine is

   ```
   foo "$A" "$B" 'some string' bar
   ```

   but `$B` should be evaluated on the *local* machine, you get

   ```
   'foo "$A" '\'"$B"\'' '\''some string'\'' bar'
   ```

   3.1 **Note:** This is not completely foolproof – it will fail if the string in `$B` contains `'`. To be safe in cases where you cannot guarantee that there is no `'` inside of `$B`, you can first execute `QQ=\'\\\'\' ; ProtectedB=${B//\'/$QQ}` and then use `'\'"$ProtectedB"\''` instead of `'\'"$B"\''` in the command above.
4. Use the result as the argument of ssh.

I assume that the following works (but I can't test it here).

```
ssh -t machine '
    cd /to/the/bin/path
    && if [ -n "$(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep server_name | awk '\''FNR == 1 {print $1}'\'')" ]
       then
           echo "podsvr is running with id $(sudo -u dev ps U dev | grep POD | awk '\''FNR == 1 {print $1}'\'')"
       else
           sudo -u dev sfservice server_name start
       fi
'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to improve the command and simplify the quoting:

1. There's no need to run `ps` using `sudo` to see processes running as another user.
2. Use the `-q` option to suppress the output of `grep`, and simply check the exit status
   to see if a match was found.
3. Use double-quotes with `echo` to allow the `svc_id` parameter to expand.
4. Use single quotes around the entire command for the argument to `ssh`.
5. Presumably, `/to/the/bin/path` is where `sfservice` lives? You can probably just specify the full path to run the command, rather than changing the working directory.

---

```
ssh -t machine 'if ps U dev -o command | grep -q -m1 server_name; then
                  svc_pid=$( ps U dev -o pid,command | grep -m1 POD | cut -d" " -f 1 )
                  echo "podsvr is running with id $svc_pid"
                else 
                  sudo -u dev /to/the/bin/path/sfservice server_name start 
                fi
'
```